# How to define and select groups of values using configobj?

Tags: python, configuration, config, configuration-files, configobj

I would like to define several groups of values where the values of a particular group are used if that group is selected.

Here's a an example to make that clearer:

```
[environment]
type=prod

[prod]
folder=data/
debug=False

[dev]
folder=dev_data/
debug=True
```

Then to use it:

```
print config['folder'] # prints 'data/' because config['environment']=='prod'
```

Is there a natural or idiomatic way to do this in configobj or otherwise?

---

*Additional Info*

My current thoughts are overwriting or adding to the resulting config object using some logic post parsing the config file. However, this feels contrary to the nature of a config file, and feels like it would require somewhat complex logic to validate.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is maybe not exactly what you're searching for, but have you considered using [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) for easy nested access?

For example, if your config file looks like

```
{
    "environment": {
        "type": "prod"
    },
    "[dev]": {
        "debug": "True",
        "folder": "dev_data/"
    },
    "[prod]": {
        "debug": "False",
        "folder": "data/"
    }
}
```

you can access it with `[dev]` or `[prod]` key to get your folder:

```
>>> config = json.loads(config_data)
>>> config['[dev]']['folder']
'dev_data/'
>>> config['[prod]']['folder']
'data/'
```

Comment: This is essentially possible in configobj. I just wanted to avoid `if config['environment']['type']=='prod'` everywhere in the code...

Comment: Oh, okay, I didn't know that. Then why not just switch config files, one for development and one for production?

Comment: @cammil Or globally set (when initializing) the `config` variable to the list you want, either `[dev]` or `[prod]`...

Comment: @cammil Did it work? In my last comment I meant setting `env = config['environment]['type']; config = config[env]` in the beginning of your code - one line to re-define the whole `config`-list to the environment specified in the beginning of your file.

Comment: That is one solution but as mentioned in the question, I'm looking for a mechanism in configobj, or an idiomatic way to deal with what would seem like a common requirement